# android setText() multiple textViews

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, performance

Hello I have  **3 Type of textViews** in my Layout with same Dynamic text but there is only one **Difference** between them i.e. .  **Postion** . I wanted to show and hide them according to Button Click . but the problem problem occurs when I have to write the same code for five Different TextViews with only one **TEXT** . Kindly Suggest me Efficient way which could reduce the number of line in my JAVA code.

```
    temperature.setText(temp);
    txt.setText(Name);
    descptxt.setText(descp);

    temperature3.setText(temp);
    txt3.setText(Name);
    descptxt3.setText(descp);

    temperature4.setText(temp);
    txt4.setText(Name);
    descptxt4.setText(descp);
```

the number of TextViews will be increase in Future . I am worried about writing same Boiler Plate Code again and Agian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function like this:

```
void setText(String name,String temp,String descp){
  for(int i=0;i<txt.size();i++){
     temperature.get(i).setText(temp);
     txt.get(i).setText(Name);
     descptxt.get(i).setText(descp);
  }
}
```

Also instead of creating different variables for each textview create an array of it.

```
ArrayList<TextView> temperature=new ArrayList<TextView>();
temperature.add((TextView)findViewById(<id>));
//Same for rest of them
```

And when you want to change text:

```
setText("","","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Store each objects in a array ie. temperature objects in a separate array. txt objects in a separate array and descp objects in a separate array.

create a method like

```
 public void setTexts(String temp,String name,String desc){
    for(TextView temperature : temperatureArray){
    //Change for loop declaration according to your code
    //set text for temperature 
temperature.setText(temp);
    }
    for(TextView txt  : txtArray){
    //Change for loop declaration according to your code
    //set text for txt  
txt.setText(name);
    }
    for(TextView descp : descpArray){ 
    //Change for loop declaration according to your code
    //set text for descp 
descp.setText(desc);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `TextView`s are logically grouped together, you might want to create one compound `View` containing all of them:

```
public class TemperatureView extends ViewGroup { //or whichever layout you use
    private TextView textView1;
    private TextView textView2;
    private TextView textView3;

    public void setData(TemperatureData data) {
        textView1.setText(...);    
        textView2.setText(...);
        textView3.setText(...);
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this is the most elegant solution in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative in which u can apply loop over childcount of parent layout instead of finding using findViewById.and then using instance of operator ,you can find textviews on which u want to perform the task.